# Relationship conditional expectation and random variable under specific constraint on its values

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, almost-everywhere

I am trying to establish a relationship between the following conditional expectation and random variable based on the a given identity:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $X,Y \in \{0,\dots, n\}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $Z \in [0,1]$ be random variables on said space. Suppose it holds that 
>   \begin{align}
> \tag{1}
> \label{1}
> P(X=Y \mid Z = z) = z \quad \forall z \in [0,1]
> \end{align}
>   What is the relationship between $\mathbb{E}[1_{X=Y} \mid Z]$ and $Z$?

I can show this implies equality in distribution. Let $W = \mathbb{E}[1_{X=Y} \mid Z]$, then for $w \in [0,1]$
\begin{align}
P(W \leq w) = \int_0^w \mathbb{E}[1_{X=Y} \mid Z = z] \,f(z) \,dz \overset{\ref{1}}{=} \int_0^w z \,f(z) \,dz = P(Z \leq z)
\end{align}
My questions are:

1. Is the other direction also true, i.e. \ref{1} $\Leftrightarrow \mathbb{E}[1_{X=Y} \mid Z] \overset{P}{=} Z$?
2. Does \ref{1} $\Leftrightarrow \mathbb{E}[1_{X=Y} \mid Z] \overset{a.s.}{=} Z$ hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on 2. is: "yes" (hence also the answer of 1. is: "yes").

$$\mathbb E\mathsf1_{X=Y}=P(X=Y)\tag2$$ and according to the same principle: $$\mathbb E[\mathsf1_{X=Y}\mid Z=z]=P(X=Y\mid Z=z)\text{ for all }z\in[0,1]\tag3$$

So $(1)$ in your question can be translated into: $$\mathbb E[\mathsf1_{X=Y}\mid Z=z]=z\text{ for all }z\in[0,1]\tag4$$ which on its turn comes to the same as:$$\mathbb E[\mathsf1_{X=Y}\mid Z)=Z\tag5$$

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it helps to write things clearly without their interpretations attached.